# Solving this recursive relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I want to solve this recursive relation:

$$i_{n+1}=4i_{n}+9$$ where the $i_1=t$ that $t \in \mathbb{N}$

I tried to make like relation about [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi), but no good thing happened.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean `make like relation about hanoi tower`?

Comment: I think changing to $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+1$ but it is bad idea as I tested it.

Comment: This a recurrence relation with constant coefficients which is easy to solve.

Comment: @science,can you give me hint how?because I stuck about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
$$i_{n+1}+3 = 4(i_n+3)$$Defining $t_n = i_n+3$, we obtain
$$t_{n+1} = 4t_n \implies t_n = 4^{n-1} t_1 \implies i_n = 4^{n-1}(i_1+3)-3$$

Answer (score 3):

$$a_{n+1}=4a_n+9$$
$$4a_n=16a_{n-1}+36$$
$$\vdots$$
$$4^{n-2}a_3=4^{n-1}a_2+4^{n-2}.9$$
$$4^{n-1}a_2=4^na_1+4^{n-1}9$$
Adding all the equations, you get $a_{n+1}=4^na_1+9(1+4+\dots+4^{n-1})$.
$$a_{n+1}=4^na_1+9\frac{4^n-1}{3}$$
$$a_n=4^{n-1}(a_1+3)-3$$

Answer (score 1):

Like all linear recurrence relations, you first solvethe homogeneous equation:
$$ \begin{cases} u_{n+1}=4u_n\\u_1=t\end{cases}$$
which is a geometric sequence.

Then you try to find one particular solution of the complete equation: $u_{n+1}=4u_n + 9$. This should be a constant, which you can calculate, setting $ u_n=C$.